# Encoding social security rules in R function

Tags: r, rule

I'm writing a function to calculate the payment amounts owed under an Australian social security program called the 'Family Tax Benefit Part A'. You can see the eligibility rules for this [program here](http://www.humanservices.gov.au/spw/corporate/publications-and-resources/resources/co029/co029-1601en.pdf).

As a simplified example, a person receives this entitlement according to the following rules:

```
(number_of_children_aged < 13) * 5412.95
(number_of_children_aged >= 13 & < 16) * 6825.5
(number_of_children_aged >= 16 & < 19 AND attends_school) * 6825.5
```

Now I could hard code these rules like this (this is just rough I'm not saying this is the ideal way to code it but you get the idea):

```
ftb_a <- function(age, school) {
    children <- data.frame(age, school)
    benefit <- 0
    benefit <- benefit + (length(children[children$age < 13,1]) * 5412.95)
    benefit <- benefit + (length(children[children$age >= 13 & children$age < 16,1]) * 6825.5)
    benefit <- benefit + (length(children[children$age >= 16 &
                                      children$age < 19 &
                                      children$school == TRUE,1]) * 6825.5)
    return(benefit)
}
```

The problem here is that the benefit amounts are hard-coded, and like any other government program they are subject to change. So this function is brittle to future changes (which will certainly occur).

So I want to be able to have the function take the parameters as arguments. The trouble that I'm having is conceptualising how to do it.

I've looked into using rules engines, but that just seems overkill and there aren't any great r packages that do it, so I'd be writing it from scratch.

So I was thinking one way to solve it would be to pass the rates and the criteria in as a matrix. Something like the following (in pseudo code):

```
rules <- c('nchildren < 13 * 5412.95',
           'nchildren >= 13 & nchildren < 16 * 6825.5',
           'nchildren >= 16 & < 19 & attends_school == TRUE')
ftb_a <- function(age, school, rules) {
    [SOMEHOW APPLY THE AGE AND SCHOOL VALUES TO THIS RULES SET]
}
```

But I'm lost as to how to:

1. Encode the rules, the different rules have different numbers of clauses e.g. rule 1 has one clause, but rules 3 has three.
2. How to then apply these rules to the data. Should I be using a subset?

Let me know if I can clarify this in some way, appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: Your rules logic is going to have exist either as a function or in a file somewhere, and either way it will have to be maintained, there is no getting around this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok encoding your rules in an external file, this may work. Just be aware that encoding will not seem as straightforward as you think (e.g. instead of measuring the length, you may need to `sum` the `TRUE` values)

```
set.seed(12)
age <- sample(1:20,20,F)
school <- sample(0:1,20,T)

library(data.table) # using this only because make the following expressions simpler
                    # however, you might find useful to review the library in detail.
dt <- data.table(age, school)

# be aware that the columns of the data table has the same names
# as the variables used to define your criteria


rules1 <- list(list(criteria="sum(age < 13)", value=5412.95), 
              list(criteria="sum(age >= 13 & age < 16)", value=6825.5), 
              list(criteria="sum(age >= 16 & age < 19 & school)", value=6825.5))
benef <- function (x) {eval(parse(text=paste("dt[,",x[[1]],"*", x[[2]],"]")))}
sum(sapply(rules1, benef))
```

Answer (score 1):

By "encode" the rules, I'm guessing you want something other than raw R code, such as an external table.

If it were me, I'd have an spreadsheet or database with the rules represented as something like this:

```
|rule.no |compare.varname |compare |benefit |
|:-------|:---------------|:-------|:-------|
|1       |child.age       |< 13    |5412.95 |
|2       |child.age       |>= 13   |6825.5  |
|2       |child.age       |< 16    |0       |
|3       |child.age       |>= 16   |6825.5  |
|3       |child.age       |< 19    |0       |
|3       |school          |== TRUE |0       |
```

Note that every line of the same rule number will be treated as a set of "AND" conditions.  For "OR" conditions, you'll need two separate rule numbers.

We'll feed the data in as a data.frame with column names which must match the names used on `compare.varname` above.

Some sample data:

```
| family.id| child.age|school |
|---------:|---------:|:------|
|         1|         5|TRUE   |
|         1|        12|TRUE   |
|         1|        18|FALSE  |
|         2|         5|TRUE   |
|         2|        13|TRUE   |
|         2|        18|FALSE  |
|         3|         5|TRUE   |
|         3|        13|TRUE   |
|         3|        18|TRUE   |
|         4|         5|TRUE   |
|         4|        13|TRUE   |
|         4|        21|TRUE   |
```

So, let's code that in.

First, the rules:

```
    ruleset <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  rule.no=1, 
  compare.varname="child.age",
  compare="< 13",
  benefit=5412.95)

ruleset[2,] <- c(
  rule.no=2, 
  compare.varname="child.age",
  compare=">= 13",
  benefit=6825.5)

ruleset[3,] <- c(
  rule.no=2, 
  compare.varname="child.age",
  compare="< 16",
  benefit=0) # max value of benefits to be selected for a rule.

ruleset[4,] <- c(
  rule.no=3, 
  compare.varname="child.age",
  compare=">= 16",
  benefit=6825.5)

ruleset[5,] <- c(
  rule.no=3, 
  compare.varname="child.age",
  compare="< 19",
  benefit=0) # 

ruleset[6,] <- c(
  rule.no=3, 
  compare.varname="school",
  compare="== TRUE",
  benefit=0)
```

And the family data

```
# some families, with every test case of child...

# ftb should be 5412.95 + 5421.95 = 10834.90
family1 <- data.frame( 
  family.id=1,
  child.age=c(5,12,18),
  school=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
)

# ftb should be 5412.95 + + 6825.50 = 12238.45
family2 <- data.frame( 
  family.id=2,
  child.age=c(5,13,18),
  school=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
)  

# ftb should be 5412.95 + + 6825.50 + 6825.50 = 19063.95  
family3 <- data.frame(
  family.id=3,
  child.age=c(5,13,18),
  school=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
)

# ftb should be 5412.95 + + 6825.50 = 12238.45
family4 <- data.frame(
  family.id=4,
  child.age=c(5,13,21),
  school=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
)


families <- rbind(family1, family2, family3, family4)
```

Now the function to parse all that.

```
 ftb.calc <- function(dat, rules,...) {
  rule.numbers <- unique(rules$rule.no)

  # in the following loops, R will be turning
  # strings into executed code. if you don't trust your
  # user base (such as in a web app), hardening 
  # this stage is crucial.
  # otherwise, instead of a simple compare, this step could 
  # be told to make a network connection and transmit a bunch of 
  # sensitive information. awkward, explaining to clients how 
  # that might've happened. hiding behind an API / interface is 
  # a good first step.

  # there's probably an astonishingly elegant way to do these 
  # loops with tapply() or by(), but this is how I prototype. 


  benefit.due <- 0.0

  for(rn in rule.numbers) {
    result <- rep(TRUE,nrow(dat))
    this.benefit <- max(as.numeric(rules$benefit[rules$rule.no == rn]))
    idx <- which(rules$rule.no == rn)
    # for each line of the rule:
    #   build a string to parse,
    #   evaluate it, then 
    #   element-wise AND with "result"
    for(ix in idx) {
      string.to.parse <- paste0(
        "dat$",
        rules[ix,"compare.varname"],
        " ",
        rules[ix,"compare"])
      loop.res <- eval(parse(file=NULL, text=string.to.parse))
      result <- result & loop.res
    } # inner loop end - steps of a rule
    benefit.due <- benefit.due + as.numeric(sum(result)) * this.benefit

  } # outer loop end - rule-by-rule
  return(benefit.due)
}
```

Let's see if that worked...

```
    by(data = families, 
   INDICES = families$family.id, 
   FUN = ftb.calc, 
   rules = ruleset)


families$family.id: 1
[1] 10825.9
----------------------------------------------------------- 
families$family.id: 2
[1] 12238.45
----------------------------------------------------------- 
families$family.id: 3
[1] 19063.95
----------------------------------------------------------- 
families$family.id: 4
[1] 12238.45
```

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Also, it's a bad idea to use "numeric" for money.  two integers (dollars, cents) is not subject to rounding error. But for this,it's probably ok.